# eclipse android programming Error in an XML file: aborting build

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i am creating an android application, a simple calculator, but i am getting an "[2012-03-12 20:22:21 - Calculator] Error in an XML file: aborting build." which i couldn't solve. could you identify the problem?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtResult"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/result"
    android:editable="false" 
    android:gravity="right">
</EditText>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1.25"
     android:text="@string/number1" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1.25"
     android:text="@string/number2" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button3"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/number3"
     android:layout_weight="1.25" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/buttonPlus"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1.25"
     android:text="@string/calcAddition" />

</LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button4"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/number4"
         android:layout_weight="1.25" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button5"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/number5" 
         android:layout_weight="1.25"/>

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button6"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/number6"
         android:layout_weight="1.25"/>

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/buttonMinus"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1.25"
         android:text="@string/calcMinus" />

</LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button7"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/number7"
         android:layout_weight="1.25" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button8"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/number8" 
         android:layout_weight="1.25"/>

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button9"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/number9" 
         android:layout_weight="1.25"/>

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/buttonMultiplication"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1.25"
         android:text="@string/calcMultiplication" />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button0"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1.02"
         android:text="@string/number0" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/buttonCLR"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="0.67"
         android:text="@string/calcCLR" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/btnCalcEqual"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/calcEqual" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/buttonDivision"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1.1"
         android:text="@string/calcDiv" />

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string name="app_name">Calculator</string>
<string name="number1">1</string>
<string name="number2">2</string>
<string name="number3">3</string>
<string name="number4">4</string>
<string name="number5">5</string>
<string name="number6">6</string>
<string name="number7">7</string>
<string name="number8">8</string>
<string name="number9">9</string>
<string name="number0">0</string>
<string name="calcCLR">CLR</string>
<string name="calcDiv">/</string>
<string name="calcMultiplication">*</string>
<string name="calcAddition">+</string>
<string name="calcMinus">-</string>
<string name="result">0</string>
<string name="calcEqual">Calculate</string>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If that is the entire xml layout then you must add on the first line this(before anything):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Also this:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

is only required only on the first element in the layout(in your case the `LinearLayout` with the id `linearLayout1`).

Edit:

On your `EditText` you set the color: `android:textColor="@layout/main"`,this is wrong. If you want a color resource then do this:

```
android:textColor="@color/the_color"
```

where `the_color` is a color set in your `colors.xml` file in the `values` folder containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="the_color">#0077cc</color>

</resources>
```

Comment: i've edited the code, both in eclipse and in this topic, but still couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Alex Have you declared all the strings you use? Also add the exception you get in the Logcat.

Comment: Yes all the strings are declared in strings.xml

Comment: @Alex Add the Exception you get. I've tested your layout and it is working  after the modification i've said above.

Comment: i've re-uploaded the strings.xml and main.xml to the question.

Comment: @Alex Check here ( http://pastebin.com/PnaH3082 ) what I've tested with your layouts(and it works). Also try to clean the project, from menu `Project -> Clean`.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that Eclipse is picky about the white space at the beginning of your XML files.

If you have the line  in your file it must appear at the beginning of the file with no white space (space or tab) preceding it.